How to preserve user session in rails backend when deactivating csrf
I am migrating the front part of an application React + RoR.
I have separated one of the React components and deployed it into a vercel host, wrapped it up with Next.js, and I am now using vercel rewrites to access the previous parts of the app I have in Heroku, with the gem react-rails.
I am using axios with relative routes in the original site, so when I access through vercel rewrites I find that the paths called are relative to the route in vercel, so I want to change those by using absolute routes in all the site, which prompt CSRF token errors, which lead me to deactivate them in all controllers. Now the current_user rails method, whenever it gets accessed from any of those calls is nil, so I don't know how to preserve the user session... without using jwt, and maintaining the code I had. Is it possible?
